# Spring Application context not getting initialised in Docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, reactor-netty

I have a spring-boot 2.2.0.RELEASE reactive-netty application that calls an external url. 
 
 **java -jar -Xms128m -Xmx128m -XX:+UseG1GC -Dapp.logger.level=debug -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dapp.postcode.masked=true -Dapp.refresh.rate=5 app.jar** works just fine in local Ubuntu machine.
 
 I create the Dockerfile as shown :

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY app.jar app.jar
CMD ["java","-Xms128m","-Xmx128m","-XX:+UseG1GC","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dapp.logger.level=debug","-Dspring.profiles.active=prod","-Dapp.postcode.masked=true","-Dapp.refresh.rate=5","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

But while running docker container,the application stops at the place where we expect to see the Spring-boot logo & the external url is not being called.

docker inspect **my-container-id** command output is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "ea077c80e45eda3443d6a55dba9f09bdd10623caa43caa30f5e20b02dde6deea",
        "Created": "2019-11-09T14:20:15.954119877Z",
        "Path": "java",
        "Args": [
            "-Xms128m",
            "-Xmx128m",
            "-XX:+UseG1GC",
            "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom",
            "-Dapp.logger.level=debug",
            "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod",
            "-Dapp.postcode.masked=true",
            "-Dapp.refresh.rate=5",
            "-jar",
            "/app.jar"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 1486,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-11-09T14:20:17.182186765Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:c857deea61b61b1e0783349a72fa23120fa8be9441347e92682cb7167bdc1eb6",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ea077c80e45eda3443d6a55dba9f09bdd10623caa43caa30f5e20b02dde6deea/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ea077c80e45eda3443d6a55dba9f09bdd10623caa43caa30f5e20b02dde6deea/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ea077c80e45eda3443d6a55dba9f09bdd10623caa43caa30f5e20b02dde6deea/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ea077c80e45eda3443d6a55dba9f09bdd10623caa43caa30f5e20b02dde6deea/ea077c80e45eda3443d6a55dba9f09bdd10623caa43caa30f5e20b02dde6deea-json.log",
        "Name": "/romantic_euler",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b8c8619145a0c996efe95e2f1de24aaaf92f18fa6565048324081f10a1e7554-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d971ed3a77711e6931f427cd65bd062db4d6557ea1ba96ac6d082375c40c686d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d89c12322ad67081600fcfdd6883bbb976ad9a7cb2b5bd38e44efef8dea8db2f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/663378a32701bfaeafa440dba0083d6d2bd9b44762c2dab496b6b0299a3f70b2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c60ec1239620758a13d72fbedac84872b413eea5a3055d29c63b30174776ac31/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b8c8619145a0c996efe95e2f1de24aaaf92f18fa6565048324081f10a1e7554/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b8c8619145a0c996efe95e2f1de24aaaf92f18fa6565048324081f10a1e7554/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b8c8619145a0c996efe95e2f1de24aaaf92f18fa6565048324081f10a1e7554/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "371e94dcfd7a6c78ddf5a0881c1ba55de815c0aa28d0d7dd1667f494112a78d1",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/371e94dcfd7a6c78ddf5a0881c1ba55de815c0aa28d0d7dd1667f494112a78d1/_data",
                "Destination": "/tmp",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "ea077c80e45e",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": true,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "StdinOnce": true,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk",
                "JAVA_VERSION=8u212",
                "JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION=8.212.04-r0"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "lbc/app:1.0.1",
            "Volumes": {
                "/tmp": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "java",
                "-Xms128m",
                "-Xmx128m",
                "-XX:+UseG1GC",
                "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom",
                "-Dapp.logger.level=debug",
                "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod",
                "-Dapp.postcode.masked=true",
                "-Dapp.refresh.rate=5",
                "-jar",
                "/app.jar"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "fc3812e69c6e3d126e7430884088fc5221060a60191b9a8e64ce01d036ac8422",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/fc3812e69c6e",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "fb23225e7424faa61e963d60c094c6554f2eb8a1b09671073a8ecdc847b921b8",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "f80c3cf8c705ee1a1827a0a31f4c96a3ddb2c8e169a696954afeb4bf99f5273c",
                    "EndpointID": "fb23225e7424faa61e963d60c094c6554f2eb8a1b09671073a8ecdc847b921b8",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Docker container log is as follows :

```
{"log":"15:10:27,805 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022802761Z"}
{"log":"15:10:27,806 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022885919Z"}
{"log":"15:10:27,807 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/bike-client.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/logback.xml]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022899799Z"}
{"log":"15:10:27,842 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@504bae78 - URL [jar:file:/bike-client.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/logback.xml] is not of type file\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022909859Z"}
{"log":"15:10:27,988 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022920574Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,003 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:95 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProperty]]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022929898Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,003 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022939844Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,025 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [jsonConsoleAppender]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022949446Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggingEventJsonProviders] for [providers] property\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022958682Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,285 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggingEventFormattedTimestampJsonProvider] for [timestamp] property\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022968453Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,296 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.MessageJsonProvider] for [message] property\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022978043Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,300 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggerNameJsonProvider] for [loggerName] property\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022987985Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,303 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.ThreadNameJsonProvider] for [threadName] property\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.022999791Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,304 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.ContextJsonProvider] for [context] property\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.023009979Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,308 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggingEventPatternJsonProvider] for [pattern] property\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.023019372Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,328 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.StackTraceJsonProvider] for [stackTrace] property\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.023028962Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,331 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.ThrowableClassNameJsonProvider] for [throwableClassName] property\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.02303855Z"}
{"log":"15:10:28,332 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.ThrowableRootCauseClassNameJsonProvider] for [throwableRootCauseClassName] property\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.023057688Z"}
{"log":"15:10:29,014 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.023068665Z"}
{"log":"15:10:29,015 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [jsonConsoleAppender] to Logger[ROOT]\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.023077791Z"}
{"log":"15:10:29,015 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.023086989Z"}
{"log":"15:10:29,017 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@3b764bce - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.02309604Z"}
{"log":"\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-11-09T15:10:29.024062248Z"}
```

I have tried with ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile but with little success. Where would I have gone wrong?

Comment: You should use entrypoint, not cmd, but that isn't what's breaking it.

Comment: have you tried with openjdk:8-jdk instead of openjdk:8-jdk-alpine? Sometimes alpines does not the same way as other linux distros do. I recommend to first get it running, then trim your image down with e.g. alpine.

Comment: In addition, it seems that you are using windows line breaks somewhere in there. Your log file is cluttered with `\r\n`

Comment: Used **FROM openjdk:8-jdk** in Dockerfile. but still the same error. No Spring boot logo after running the docker container.

Comment: I gave a wrong profile **-Dspring.profiles.active=prod1** but still, get the same error as above instead of error getting **prod1 profile cannot be found**. Am I passing system property to java command incorrectly in **Dockerfile** ?

Comment: **java -jar app.jar** runs successfully in my machine and so does **ENTRYPOINT ["java","-version"]**. But **ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]** shows no spring-boot logo. Actually the system properties are missing and the docker run command must complain of that but doesn't. Which configuration am I missing here ?